# UndefVarError: * not defined

Tags: julia

I'm having a persistent error where Julia tells me that the multiplication operator is undefined when I use multiplication within a package I'm working on. Nowhere in the package do I redefine or expand the Base multiplication operator, and there are some places where multiplication is recognized and others where it is not. For example, in the following code

```
    Λ = h.metric.Λ # Type Int64
    kSize = 2*Λ+1
    for i = 1:n_steps
        # Tempering
        r = temper(lf, r, (i=i, is_half=true), n_steps)
        # Take a half leapfrog step for momentum variable
        r = r - map(gradi -> ϵ / 2 .* gradi, grad)
```

the multiplication on line 2 gives me `UndefVarError: * not defined` wheras the multiplication on the last line compiles and executes without the error.

Multiplication outside the package and in the Julia REPL on Visual Studio Code does not seem to have the same error.

I've tried `Using Base: *` and `import Base.*` in both the main module and the individual Julia packages in the file to no avail. Any ideas about what could be going on?

Answer (score 8):

This will appear if you accidentally *assign* to `*` later in the function or in a branch that didn't get taken.  An easy place where this could happen is in an `if` expression that intends to ask if `a*b == c` but mistakenly uses `=` instead of `==`:

```
julia> function test(a, b, c)
           d = a*b
           if (a*b = c)
               println("got $d")
           end
       end
test (generic function with 1 method)

julia> test(2,3,6)
ERROR: UndefVarError: * not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] test(a::Int64, b::Int64, c::Int64)
   @ Main ./REPL[4]:2
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[5]:1
```

Comment: TIL that you can define operators in Julia with `a*b =` instead of needing the more verbose, but safer, `Base.:(*)(a,b) =`. Seems dangerous.

Comment: See issues [#15483](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15483) and [#17730](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/17730).

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible example, and full error message it is difficult to help. The only context that I can think of in which `*` would be undefined is within [`baremodule`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Default-top-level-definitions-and-bare-modules)

```
julia> *
* (generic function with 328 methods)

julia> module M1
       *
       end
Main.M1

julia> baremodule M2
       *
       end
ERROR: UndefVarError: * not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[2]:2
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's hard to reproduce this error and the error message doesn't say much more than `UndefVarError`. No where in the package do I use `baremodule` instead of `module`. Thanks for the help.